# Does NULL have to be converted in order to use it in concatenations or calculations?

Tags: php, function, null

this is a quite short question, but it really interests me. I know that null literally means 'nothing', but if you want it to be concatenated with a string or used in a calculation, is it better/ faster than using the appropriate data type?

Imagine these two (useless) functions as an example:

```
function concat1($str1, $str2 = null) {
    return $str1 . $str2;
}

function concat2($str1, $str2 = '') {
    return $str1 . $str2;
}
```

Is one of these types of declaring the function more recommended or am I unnecessarily trying to optimize my code?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes it has to be converted, because concatenation is a string operation, so it gets converted to an empty string to allow it to be concatenated (or to a 0 for a mathematical operation)

Comment: As to whether it's better/faster, stop worrying about such micro-optimisations (you'd never be able to measure the difference accurately); I can guarantee that they'll be much bigger inefficiencies in your code that that

Comment: You might even find that `return ($str2 === null) ? $str1 : $str1 . $str2;` is faster for longer strings

Comment: I understand, thank you very much, it cleared some things up for me!